Public ip usage charge in AWS
I can't understand why am I being charged for using public ip v4 address, if I haven't used 750 free hours in a free tier.


Im new in AWS, I've been using default ec2 instance created with web gui,  and I was following default creation process.

Started last February 2024, AWS now charge for IPv4. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/

It seems that your ip address is not used because of ec2 stopped or any reason. Check the ip is connected somewhere and using. The idle one will be charged.
